# class not registered vfp web service

Tags: web, ole, visual-foxpro

I'm following the vfp web service walk-trough. But when I test the result in the task pane i receive an error. It was :

Error: 1429 - OLE IDispatch exception code 0 from WSDLOperation: WSDLOperation:Instantiating the dispatch object for method xxxx failed HRESULT=0x80040154: Class not registered.

xxxx is my method.

I've registered the dll and set the authorisation in IIS.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like when the VFP module was compiled, the "OlePublic" class instance never was properly put into the Windows Registry.  Sometimes VFP will NOT register if you not in an administrative level to allow writing to the registry.  If that is the case, make sure you start VFP as "Admin" user before compiling the app.

Also, are you building it as a single or multithreaded DLL instance.  In addition, if you right-click / "Project Info" of your project, and click on the "Servers" tab, it should show all your OlePublic classes.  What is the "Instancing" setting... single / multi?

Additionally, it could be a "permissions" thing.  If the service you are trying to load it as (ie: ASP.NET user account or similar) and that user doesn't have permissions and/or access to the file, then it won't allow the object to be created.

To just TEST if the object is in the registry or not, you could always just start an instance of VFP, and from the command window, try to do a

objTesting = CREATEOBJECT( "YourClass.YourObject" )

if it works that way, then I would look more into the permissions avenue.

FOLLOW-UP

@wongchungyie, I'm not sure of if that was the problem or not, but more likely permissions.  One time, when changing development machines, I too had a problem trying to create an instance of my OlePublic COM server class.  TO ENSURE what the problem was, I started a simple program in VFP that did nothing BUT

```
set procedure to YourClassThatHasOlePublic
set step on
o = createObject( "YourOlePublicClass" )
```

Then, as the "CreateObject" is going through all the initialization, you might find some "path" is not available, or permissions, or whatever...  Find and fix that element and I was able to continue work for my client.

Hope this gives you something to work with.

Comment: it was multithreaded...could you please inform me whether it was right? how does single / multi effect my project? thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @wongchungyie, see revision/expanded answer.